# Get the sum of an associated column in a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

My model's set up like so

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :predictions

end

class Prediciton < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :score
  belongs_to :user
end
```

What I want to do is grab the sum of all the values in the score column for each user.

So far I have come up with this in my view:

```
<% @user.each do |u| %>
 <% u.predictions.each do |h| %>
  <%= u.name %><%= h.score %>

 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

but my controller is just

```
@user = User.all
```

I was thinking something like this may work?

```
@user = User.all
@scores = @user.predictions.where("fixture_date <= ?", Date.today).sum(:score)
```

but it doesn't. Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: Don't use `attr_accessible` for columns that are backed by the database. ActiveRecord will automatically create setters and getters based on the database schema.

Comment: Aside from the aggregation, in any of the answers it would be best to move the `.where("fixture_date <= ?", Date.today)` logic into a scope on the `Prediction` model, and either merge it into the statement or merge it into a new association (which would then allow eager loading of the association).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add sum score to user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :predictions

  def sum_score
    predictions.where("fixture_date <= ?", Date.today).sum(:score)
  end
end
```

In view:

```
<% @user.each do |u| %>
  <%= u.name %><%= u.sum_score %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Nice!! thanks v much, why i didn't think of that i don't know

Comment: how would i order the results? so :order => "score, DESC" for example

Comment: Do you want to sort the users based on the score sum? It can't be done on db side, the sum is calculated on display. But you can sort the `@user` result set in the controller: `@user = User.all.sort{|a, b| a.sum_score <=> b.sum_score}`

Comment: "It can't be done on db side" - nope. Thats just wrong. You just need to select the aggregate to be able to use it in the query.

Comment: @max Well, technically anything can be done. I upvote your solution, as it does a good job on that.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is not actually that good since it gives a N+1 query issue since each row fetched will cause a query to fetch the sum. And it does not let you order by the aggregate.

What you want is to perform a custom select:

```
@users = User.joins(:predictions)
    .where("fixture_date <= ?", Date.today)
    .select('users.*, SUM(predications.score) AS total_score')
    .group('users.id')
```

This will return an ActiveRecord::Relation object containing full user records.

```
irb(main):031:0> @users.each { |u| puts "User #{u.id} has a total score of #{u.total_score}"}
User 2 has a total score of 2
User 1 has a total score of 5
=> [#<User id: 2, email: nil, password_digest: nil, created_at: "2018-09-03 06:04:57", updated_at: "2018-09-03 06:04:57">, #<User id: 1, email: nil, password_digest: nil, created_at: "2018-09-03 06:01:45", updated_at: "2018-09-03 06:01:45">]
```

As you can see from the example ActiveRecord will actually magically create accessors for any additional columns that you fetch.

You can use the column to sort by applying `.order`:

```
@users = User.joins(:predictions)
    .where("fixture_date <= ?", Date.today)
    .select('users.*, SUM(predications.score) AS total_score')
    .group('users.id')
    .order('total_score DESC')
```

Altogether you get something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :predictions

  def self.ordered_by_score
    self.joins(:predictions)
        .where("fixture_date <= ?", Date.current)
        .group('users.id')
        .order('total_score DESC')
  end
end
```

Comment: This is way better than accepted answer. Accepted answer hitting N+1 queries :(

Comment: You can use `left_outer_joins` in Rails 5 if you want to include users without any predictions in the result set. https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/24/support-for-left-outer-joins-in-rails-5.html

Comment: ordering by the column  alias `total_score` might not work on some databases, so be prepared to use `order('SUM(predications.score) DESC')` if necessary.

Comment: True @DavidAldridge, I can confirm that it does work on postgres though.

Comment: Yep, I think Oracle would be problematic, and might also require `group('users.*')`